How to fix Image variable that is null during playtesting?
So currently I’m making inventory functions for my Michael game. I was making a script called RespawnItem.
public class RespawnItem : MonoBehaviour
{
//----PUBLICS----//
public PlayerCollectingSystem playerCollect;
public Image img;

//----PRIVATES----//

//----SERIALIZED PRIVATES----//
[SerializeField] private Transform playerLocation;
[SerializeField] private GameObject protag;


private void Awake()
{
    img = GetComponent<Image>();
    playerLocation = GetComponent<Transform>();
    playerCollect = protag.GetComponent<PlayerCollectingSystem>();
}

public void Respawn()
{
    
        if (img.overrideSprite == gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite)
        { 
            transform.position = playerLocation.position;
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
        }

}
}

The RespawnItem script is for spawning back the collected item when its image is clicked within the inventory slot.
The RespawnItem script is attached to a GameObject called "item".
The Image variable img is the image which is stored in the inspector.
I found a null reference exception in
img.overrideSprite == gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite, which says:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is where the variable img is null.
When I tested and played the game, I found that the image was no longer in the img variable of the inspector. When I stopped playtesting, it was back in the variable. This was the reason why it was null.
So, I know what is null and it is the img variable. The reason why it was null was because it was missing while I was playtesting it.
I looked up how to fix it and I read from Copilot, an AI that learns from other sources, and the one that stuck to me was to Reimport the script. Others seemed unlikely related to the issue, especially when it referred to "Syntax Errors". Syntax Errors appear when there is misspelling.
The only problem was that I do not know how to fix it.
I'm thinking that it could be the GetComponent but I do not know how to fix that.
This video is just for visual aid.
How should I fix this issue?

did you mean to set the variable  in your if? if (img.overrideSprite = gameObject.GetComponent<BetterItemScript>().image)  (eg do you not mean ==?)

Once you fix the if statement as mentioned in the previous comment, then you can move on. First, you are using GetComponent so it means the Image component has to be on the same game object, not in a child of it.  If the Image component is in a child then you need to use GetComponentInChildren. That is because GetComponent only scans the current GO, not any of the children

Update: I have edited the code where you have told me to change: 'img = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>();' to 'img = GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Image>();' and 'gameObject.GetComponent().image' to 'gameObject.GetComponentInChildren().image'. It is still found to be null. My purpose for this script is to spawn an object based on the image of the inventory.

There's not enough info in the question to reproduce the problem. Please include all steps to reproduce the issue starting from a blank project. See [mre] and [ask].

Sorry I forgot to tell you that the question has been updated. I have included a paragraph before the bottom question. I also edited to add a link as well.

The question doesn't describe the contents that need to be in the scene to reproduce the observed behavior. Also no mention of any components. Are there any Image components actually in the scene? How do those components relate to the game object that RespawnItem is attached to? Please re-read [mre] and include all pertinent information for reproducing the problem.  The only help you can receive until then are going to just be random guesses about what the problem is, such as by Bugfinder and Everts.  Also, please include the error message verbatim, instead of trying to summarize it

I have changed and made improvements on my question. I finally found the issue on why it was null. The only problem was that I don't know how to fix it.
